# What's the correct word for "demandingness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, if your promotor is kind, you would thank him as:

> "I thank Prof Smith for his kindness."

Now, what if your promotor is demanding, as in tough 
 and exigent when it comes to work? How do you express 
 this quality?

It seems to me the following is **not** correct English:

> I thank Prof Smith for his "demandingness".

Which is the right word to replace "demandingness" above?

If it could help the forum 
 choose, I need here to convey also the impression of 
 "at times excessive but on the whole beneficial".

Comment: Note that if you do thank him for demandingness, it could sound like an insult.  It has a nuance of habitually asking *too* much, not merely asking for rigor.

Comment: I thank Prof S for **holding me to high standards**.

Comment: I want single word. Plus the sense of "At times excessive but on the whole beneficial" is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a noun,[demandingness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demandingness) is a correct term:

> - the quality of being demanding.

(Collins)

or:

- You may thank him for being demanding, [rigorous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rigorous) or [exacting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exacting).

Comment: I should have checked demandingness. It sounds so unusual to my ear, I assumed it didn't exist!